# How can I tell whether a variable is global or local?

Tags: python, variables, global, local

How can I tell whether a variable in Python is global or local?

Comment: Can you say more about exactly what you're doing? It's rather unusual to need to be able to tell whether a variable is local or global, and there might well be a better way to solve whatever issue you're facing.

Comment: Well, for one, if it's not in `globals()`, then it's definitely not global.

Comment: Hi, I need to know whether the variables are global or local because the task I'm doing requires documentation and so I need to record a number of things. I'm making a treasure hunt game and have created multiple subroutines to account for the user choosing the grid size, inputting their movements etc. In the choosing grid size subroutine, I've used a variable called 'choice' but have also used this in the main s/r to account for what choice is made at main menu. In this case, is the variable global since it is used multiple times for different processes, or local?

Comment: @Ellie As long as you didn't used `global choice` in your function / subroutine, the local variable will be used in the function

Comment: Now you know why global variables are generally frowned upon. The easiest way to keep track if you must use them is to use a naming convention.

Answer (score 3):

globals() will return a dict of global variables

locals() will return a dict of local variables

to check if the scope of the variable:

```
if 'variable' in locals(): print("It's local") #Replace 'variable' with the variable
elif 'variable' in globals(): print("It's global") #But keep the quotation marks
else: print("It's not defined")
```

If you don't know about scopes, heres a good page to go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/7486769

Comment: Hi, how do I use this exactly to check? Please bear with me because I'm only a student and don't have a great deal of complex understanding in terms of python. If I just paste this at the bottom of my code will it output the variables that are global/ local?

Comment: I would change the order of `var in globals()` and `var in locals()`. When a var is in `locals` and in `globals` the local variable will be used.

Comment: BTW `globals()` and `locals()` returns `dict` not `list`

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is making a list for some documentation, all you need to do is create a list of variables that are defined outside of any function or class.

```
var1 = "something"

def foo():
    var2 = "something"
```

In the above, `var1` is global, `var2` is local.